# Getting system resolution without dpi effecting the return

Tags: c#, .net

Currently writing a function that will return the current resolution of the system but having difficulties. I am after the desktop resolution (its an image downloader so I will be searching for images at a certain resolution).

Currently I have tried two different ways, my first attempt was the following:

```
private Size GetMonitorResolution()
{
    Size temp = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    return temp;
}
```

This function only works if the DPI isn't scaled, for example I have a 15" laptop running at 1920x1080 but I have scaled text to 125% because it would be way too tiny to read if I didn't. This function is outputting the resolution of 1536x864 on this laptop. I have also tried similar calls like SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize but this also returns 1536x864 which is incorrect.

My second attempt is a mixture of material I found by googling the problem, but it was still returning 1536x864. That function looked like this:

```
private Size GetMonitorResolution()
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        return new Size((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * (int)graphics.DpiX) / 96
          , (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * (int)graphics.DpiY) / 96);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I could have bet money that `GetSystemMetrics()` was going to come into play.

Comment: The GetDeviceCaps function may also help. Also, using the Graphics class you can get the DPI settings, which you could probably use to calculate the original resolution from the values returned by PrimaryScreen

Comment: I will have a look at your suggestions. I don't know how the DPI effects the resolution otherwise I would just work it out manually.